# Error 1004 Paste Method of Worksheet class failed

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy data from multiple workbooks into a single one. Following is the code I am using. but is is giving error 1004 "Paste Method of Workshet class failed and stuck at code `ActiveSheet.Paste` when debug. Any help is highly appreciated.

```vb
Public Sub ImportTextFile()
    Dim TextFile As Workbook
    Dim OpenFiles() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    
    
    OpenFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select Files(s) to Import", MultiSelect:=True)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
        For i = 1 To Application.CountA(OpenFiles)
        
    Set TextFile = Workbooks.Open(OpenFiles(i))
    
    TextFile.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
    Workbooks(1).Activate
    Workbooks(1).Worksheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveSheet.Name = TextFile.Name
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    TextFile.Close
    Next i

    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Adding a worksheet probably clears the clipboard. Try moving the line of code that copies below the one that adds a new worksheet

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
```

Declaring the ws object.

```
TextFile.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
Set ws = Workbooks(1).Worksheets.Add
ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
ws.Name = TextFile.Name
```

instead of activation, you can set the objects. This will be faster as well.

Comment: tried and now getting Error 438 and at line ws.Range("A1").Paste

Comment: Right. Updated the line with Paste Special function. this will work.

Comment: Again Runtime error 1004 ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll